# R getting the next value of current column

Tags: r, data.table, rolling-computation

I have a `data.table` like:

```
DT = data.table(ColumnA = c(1.51, 1.86, 3.54, 3.79, 7.7))
```

I am trying to create `ColumnB` which holds the next value of `ColumnA`:

```
    columnA      ColumnB  

     1.51          1.86
     1.86          3.54   
     3.54          3.79
     3.79          7.70
     7.70
```

I tried the following and it was working, however now it is not working:

````
          ``` DT[, ColumnB:=c(NA,ColumnA[.I + 2]) ]```
````

I am getting this error:

> Error in .Call() : Supplied 18391 items to be assigned to 18390 items
>   of column 'ColumnB'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep()
>   to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're writing `data.table` code, so you're in luck! The `shift` function is what you're after:

```
DT[ , ColumnB := shift(ColumnA, type = 'lead')]
```

Since you're doing some analysis with `shift`, be sure to also see the other related functions `data.table` has to offer: `nafill`, `frollsum`/`frollmean`/`froll`, etc.

As to why your code is not working:

```
c(NA, ColumnA[.I + 2])
```

The first element is `NA`; the next is a vector subset of `ColumnA` at indices `.I+2`. `.I + 2` is all of the elements of `.I`, shifted up by `2`. `.I` has the same length as `ColumnA`, so `ColumnA[.I + 2]` will also have the same length as `ColumnA` -- hence `c(NA, ColumnA[.I + 2])` has *one more element than `ColumnA`*.

That's why you see the off-by-one note in your error:

> Supplied 18391 items to be assigned to 18390 items

If you wanted to do a subset approach (which will be slower), you could do:

```
DT[ , ColumnA := c(NA, ColumnA[-1L])]
```

`ColumnA[-1L]` is `ColumnA`, *minus* the *first* element, hence there are one fewer elements than are in `ColumnA` and when we combine with `NA`, we have the right number.